# Please how can I get the first child from an array with is code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data that has an array that comes from props. Please how can I render the startdate from the first child of the array?  I tried this

```
  const { event, match } = props;

  const  date = event.eventsession[0].startdate
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but i think you can .I have used it in a similar way passing an Icon prop in a component and remember that capitalization matters in jsx to recognise components you made(thats why all functional components are capitalized).You could also look into the render method of react-dom (ReactDom.render())

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. I have also used it before now but recently it starts throwing error message of "cannot read property of 0 if undefined"